# publishing web template is invisible and team site template does not contain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, site-template

I have created two web templates one of them is based on Team site and the other one based on publishing site. I have used a farm scoped feature to deploy both of them. I have two problems.

1. My publishing site template is invisible (publish features are activated). following is elements.xml file and the onet file is from \15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\PUBLISHING\XML

   ```
     <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
       <WebTemplate
         Name="WTMyPubishsite"
         BaseTemplateName="CMSPUBLISHING"
         BaseTemplateID="39"
         BaseConfigurationID="0"
         Title="Min Publishsite"
         Description="Denna mall är gjord för att skapa teamsite arbetstya."
         DisplayCategory="Addnode Group"/>
     </Elements>
   ```
2. My second problem is about the team site template. I copied onet.xml from \15\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\XML. the problem is non of the default apps are there. and home.aspx is empty.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Do you ever solve why the publishing site is invisible?

Comment: publishing feature was not activatd